# links not working with onClick tracking code

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

I have two buttons that when on my dev server worked fine as links and for tracking. Since uploading to the final server, both links no longer work?

See: http://chaqwa.com/no/meetanolympian/index.html
It's the "KONKURRANSEREGLER" link and the "contact oss" red button

```
<li><a href="konkurranseregler.html" onclick="javascript:kenshoo_conv('rules','0','','sem','NOK');return false;">KONKURRANSEREGLER</a></li>

<div class ="contactButton"> <a href="http://www.altavdrikke.no/#top" onclick="javascript:kenshoo_conv('kontakt','0','','sem','NOK');return false;"><span>Kontakta Oss</span></a></div>
```

Any ideas why they work on one server and not the other?

Comment: Thank you fsodano. Hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Seems not to work! See http://www.undergroundblc.co.uk/chaqwa/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the javascript: prefix is used in the "href" attribute, to specify you want to execute JavaScript code. If you're using the "onclick" attribute (or any other event attribute) you don't need to add the javascript: prefix.

So, try this:

```
<li><a href="konkurranseregler.html" onclick="kenshoo_conv('rules','0','','sem','NOK');return false;">KONKURRANSEREGLER</a></li>

<div class ="contactButton"> <a href="http://www.altavdrikke.no/#top" onclick="kenshoo_conv('kontakt','0','','sem','NOK');return false;"><span>Kontakta Oss</span></a></div>
```